# how to get version of default browser on my mac os x

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, browser, system-information

I want to get system information in mac using objective C.
I am searching a lot but did not got single line of code for
my use.They provided solutions via javascript but i want them in
objective C.
Provide me some help to go ahead.

Comment: what kind of system information ?

Comment: Its like current user, workgroup,ip of my own system.Default brwser is one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and works well

```
        NSWorkspace *nsSharedWorkspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
         NSString *nsAppPath = [nsSharedWorkspace fullPathForApplication:appName];
         NSBundle *nsAppBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath: nsAppPath];
         NSDictionary *nsAppInfo = [nsAppBundle infoDictionary];

//Now you can print all dictionary to view all its contents and pick which you want
         NSLog(@"%@",nsAppInfo);

//or you can get directly using following methods
         NSLog(@"%@",[nsAppInfo objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]);
         NSLog(@"%@",[nsAppInfo objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]);
```

Dont forget to add AppKit framework

Answer (score 2):

You can use launch services to get the path to the default browser as below

```
LSGetApplicationForURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString: @"http:"],
                                kLSRolesAll, NULL, (CFURLRef *)&appURL);

NSString *infoPlistPath = [[appURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents/info.plist"];
```

Now read the CFBundleShortVersionString from the info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
NSString *userName=NSUserName();
NSLog(@"UserName: %@",userName);

NSArray *ipAddress=[[NSHost currentHost] addresses];
NSLog(@"IP Address=%@",ipAddress[0]);
```

*Updating my answer*