# open file:///tmp/f.txt in default browser on osx from the command line

Tags: macos, file, browser

`open http://stackoverflow.com/` on the command line opens up my default browser on osx.

I also want to load a url like `file:///tmp/f.txt` in the default browser.

I know I can do `open -a Google\ Chrome file:///tmp/f.txt` to open it in Chrome, but what if the user has Safari set as their default browser. I'd like `open` to use the **default** browser.

`open file:///tmp/f.txt` opens up the file in TextEdit :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/613362/discover-default-browser-programmatically-on-mac) I've come up with this.

`open -a "$(VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=1 perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "http")[1]')" file:///tmp/f.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Check out what's available in NSWorkspace.

I'm thinking either [`openURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:) or [`openFile:withApplication:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openFile:withApplication:) might be what you are looking for.

And if you need to know what the default browser is, [the answer from Suhas in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406479/981049) should be the answer you can start with.

Comment: Thanks but NSWorkspace doesn't look like command line tools, unless I'm reading it wrong. That related question is also using objective C and not the command line.